# useEffect TypeError: not iterable

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am banging my head against the wall here. I want to add the pick number onto playerOne array.

```
  const [pick, setPick] = useState(1);
  const [playerOne, setPlayerOne] = useState([]);
  const [playerTurn, setPlayerTurn] = useState("X");

  useEffect(() => {
    setPlayerOne([...playerOne, ...pick]);
  }, [pick, playerOne]);
```

Here is the error I get

```
TypeError: pick is not iterable
(anonymous function)
src/App.js:28
  25 | const [playerTurn, setPlayerTurn] = useState("X");
  26 | 
  27 | useEffect(() => {
> 28 |   setPlayerOne([...playerOne, ...pick]);
     | ^  29 | }, [pick, playerOne]);
```

I have used .push() and that gives the same error.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`pick` is number. Can't be spread. Directly add it.

```
useEffect(() => {
    setPlayerOne([...playerOne, pick]);
  }, [pick, playerOne]);
```